# Custom compose key sequences without xim (e.g. in Sublime Text 2)

Tags: sublime-text, compose-key

I have quite a few custom compose key sequences.  I know I can get them working with an `~/.XCompose` and switching the input method to `xim`.  However, Sublime Text 2 doesn't accept any compose key sequences when I'm using `xim`.  It does accept them when I'm using the default input method.  I think I reported this bug for Sublime Text 2 a while ago.

Using the default input method, I added the contents of my `~/.XCompose` to `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` but this did not change anything.  Is there any way I can get the compose key sequences in my `~/.XCompose` to work without relying on `xim`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know you asked this a year ago, but in case it ever helps someone, here’s what worked for me to enable custom `.XCompose` additions:

```
sudo apt-get install uim
export "GTK_IM_MODULE=uim"
(log out and in again)
```

uim is an input method which respects the compose file additions, but also enables the functionality not available in xim, eg `Ctrl+Shift+U` to enter a hex Unicode character ID.

This may work for the OP’s situation, if he still needs a solution, I don’t know.

Comment: Finally! After running into so many problems with xim and ibus, this finally solved my problem. You can also enable uim only for Sublime Text, by using `export GTK_IM_MODULE=uim subl`.

Comment: In theory this sounds amazing but it doesn't work for me either and Ctrl+Shift+U is still disabled. :(

Answer (score 4):

[What @coteyr says](https://askubuntu.com/a/296711/81372) is, in fact, not correct. Sublime Text uses standard GTK input method API, however, it does so incorrectly.

---

I made [a package](http://whitequark.org/blog/2014/04/14/xcompose-support-in-sublime-text/) that fixes Sublime Text. You can find all the details on the bug and my workaround on my blog post but here's a quick overview of the installation:

1. Add the `sublime-imethod-fix`-PPA to your APT sources by executing the following command:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:whitequark/sublime-imethod-fix
   ```
2. Install the bugfix package that corresponds with your Sublime Text version:

   - for XCompose support in ST2:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install libsublime-text-2-xim-xcompose
     ```
   - for XCompose support in ST3:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install libsublime-text-3-xim-xcompose
     ```
3. Restart Sublime Text (if it's running). Compose sequences should now work fine.

Comment: Does not work with Sublime 3064, dev channel. ST3 doesn't even start.

Comment: @GuiAmbros Use ST3 stable for now. I'll look into it a bit later

Comment: I fixed by changing to uim instead of xim. I wrote about the experience here https://wrgms.com/using-xcompose-with-chrome-and-sublime-text/

Comment: It worked ok for me

Answer (score 2):

This is a hugely random guess, but I think it's because Sublime Text is using a different widget library and that one isn't setup for xim input.

You can try (if you haven't already) setting up persistent configuration at [this link](https://wiki.kubuntu.org/ComposeKey#Configuration_for_Gtk_Applications_.28Gnome.2C_FireFox.2C_etc..29)

If that doesn't work you can always hack IM support back in.

[This post](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7006&sid=50cfea9b8fb28114867fc217f47daf8a&start=10#p41343) should assist with that.

Both are pretty technical and both mean going out of your way a bit to make it work.

Comment: I tried cjacker's solution from your second link but wasn't able to get it to work. If anyone has had some more luck with this I'd greatly appreciate it if you could outline your steps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround for Sublime Text 2 specifically. Install [this package](https://github.com/xgenvn/InputHelper), either via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/) or manually:

```
cd ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages

git clone https://github.com/xgenvn/InputHelper.git
```

After restarting Sublime you can access an input window for composed key sequences with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the sequence at the cursor position.